# HashSet disjoint() complexity

Tags: java, time, collections, complexity-theory

What is the big O/time complexity for Java Collections disjoint() Method for two hash sets of integers?

Would appreciate any help, really stumped as I'm not sure if it's O(1) or O(n).

I know the hash set contains is an O(1) operation , but I'm not sure if the disjoint operation loops through all the elements of set 1 and checks if set 2 contains any of these elements.

Comment: What is your reasoning for either of those two possibilities you're suggesting?

Comment: I know the hash set contains is an O(1) operation , but I'm not sure if the disjoint operation loops through all the elements of set 1 and checks if set 2 contains any of these elements. Thank you for your speedy response :)

Comment: You should put info like that into your question, please [edit] it, thanks.

Comment: Will do, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's O(n).

Let's assume the set query is O(1). You need to iterate through one of the sets, and make queries in the other set to see if it contains the items.

Therefore, the set iterations take O(n) time at least (you can choose to iterate the set with a smaller size. That's what they did in the source code).

In total, time complexity is O(n).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, do you know of a faster/more efficient way to do this? Hope you're staying well :)

Comment: Note that if we differentiate `n` into the size of the smaller `a` and bigger set `b`, we easily get `O(a)` which can make quite a difference.

Comment: I just check the source code. They choose to iterate the set with a smaller size.  if (c1size > c2size) {
                iterate = c2;
                contains = c1;
 }

Comment: Thanks again to you both :)